# Eliminate need for & inside less wrapper to prepend to selector without adding space

Tags: less, dreamweaver

Here is my code:

```
.html-default-tag-color {color: #99cdff}
.html_specific-tag-colors() {
    .cm-m-xml.cm-tag- {
        &img {color: #909}
        &table, &th, &td, &tr {color: #099}
        &form {color: orange; font-weight: bold}
    }
}
```

... Above used latter in the following mixin ...
    Only interested in eliminating "&" in ABOVE

```
#makeImportant() 
{                                           
    .HTML {
        &.cm-m-xml.cm-tag {.html-default-tag-color};

        .html_specific-tag-colors();
    }
    // important required to override usage in code outside my control
} & { #makeImportant() !important}
```

Must be done in less -- runs inside Dreamweaver configured less environment.

Comment: No way (technically the nesting and & were never meant to be used for a single selector element concatenation - it's just useful but sometimes dangerous side-effect).

Comment: kind of suspected after lot of goggling but thought it was worth asking -- thanks.  Not a big deal -- was just for cosmetics.